# does time function handles time zone changes when the application is running

Tags: c, timezone, localtime

```
while (utc_service_status.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_RUNNING){

    time(&secs);
    tptr1 = localtime( &secs );
    local_secs = mktime( tptr1 );
    tptr2 = gmtime( &secs );
    tptr2->tm_isdst = -1;
    gmt_secs = mktime( tptr2 );
    diff_secs = (local_secs - gmt_secs);
    *utc_bias = diff_secs/60;
}
```

This is the sample code.when this service is running am changing the timezone.

Comment: It depends when you are setting the time & when the service application is fetching the time . If it happens only during boot and not getting updated then it is not automatic.

Comment: Please show some code, preferrably a minimized example.

Comment: while (utc_service_status.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_RUNNING){

    time(&secs);

    tptr1 = localtime( &secs );

    local_secs = mktime( tptr1 );

    tptr2 = gmtime( &secs );

    tptr2->tm_isdst = -1;

    gmt_secs = mktime( tptr2 );

    diff_secs = (local_secs - gmt_secs);

    *utc_bias = diff_secs/60;

}

Comment: please refer the sample code above.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, this depends on your implementation of *localtime* and how it chooses to do time zone conversion.

The manual page for *localtime(3)* on Linux says:

> Time zone
>   adjustments are performed as specified by the TZ environment variable (see tzset(3)).  The function localtime() uses tzset(3) to initialize time
>   conversion information, if tzset(3) has not already been called by the process.

It also adds this note, under "BUGS":

> The C Standard provides no mechanism for a program to modify its current local timezone setting, and the POSIX-standard method is not reentrant.
>   (However, thread-safe implementations are provided in the POSIX threaded environment.)

So this seems to suggest "probably not." You might find it useful to test yourself, with a program that calls *localtime*, then changes the `TZ` environment variable (and/or the `/etc/timezone` symlink) and calls *localtime* again.

Comment: That's the kind of detail that would be useful to include in the question :-)  Time zone management is more a function of the operating system than of a programming language.